# How to send large data with JQuery.ajax and Receive it with C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

Currently I am sending it with plain JS:

```
xhttp.open("POST", "interaction/TradeTransfer.aspx?action=transfer", false);
xhttp.send(transferXML);
```

In C# I am evaluating the url arguments and then reading the data with:

```
StreamReader reader3 = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);           
string transferXML = reader3.ReadToEnd();
```

I want to change from plain JS to JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "interaction/TradeTransfer.aspx?action=trade&Id=" + caller.id.toString(),           
        type: "POST",         
        data: { value : transferXML },
        dataType: "xml",           
        processData: false,

        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //data - response from server
            console.log(" createTradeOffer success");             
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(" createTradeOffer error");               
        }
    });
```

The C# StreamReader  now return only the string "[object Object]".

How do I read the data from "transferXML" in C#? Or what do I have to change in the $.Ajax call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`$.ajax` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) has an example:

```
var xmlDocument = [create xml document];
var xmlRequest = $.ajax({
  url: "page.php",
  processData: false,
  data: xmlDocument
});
```

You have to change `data: { value : transferXML }` to `data: transferXML`.

As you pointed out it might also be necessary to specify the `Content-Type` of the request message body: `contentType: 'text/xml'`

Comment: The browser console shows the error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://localhost:59335/game02/interaction/TradeTransfer.aspx?action=trade&commNodeId=5

type: "POST"
is definitely needed, else the data is put as a parameter into the url. But the error about "Failed to laod ressource" remains...

Comment: As the error message implies this is a server error. It is unrelated to your JavaScript code. Yes, `type: 'POST'` is required in your case, I just used the example from the documentation.

Comment: Partly correct, but for it to work I needed the additional:
contentType: "xml"
in the ajax call.
Add it to yout answer and I will accept it.